# How can I change my character's league?

Tags: path-of-exile

I wanted to play with my friends this game and on invite it kept saying that "the character is out of my league" even though we were the same level. I am in *domination league* and they are *normal league*. I guess I din't saw the league when I created my characters.
I read [here](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Leagues) that there are different leagues and you can not join another league. That is pretty stupid considering the I have spent a few days building some characters.

**Question:**
Is there any way I can change my character's league? I want to move them from *domination league* to *normal league*.

Comment: If you're still level 1, why not just create a new character on the correct league?

Comment: [Do not use backticks for emphasis.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7437)

Comment: @FEichinger: I though the same rules applies as stackoverflow.com formatting

Comment: @machineaddict They don't. Every site makes its own guidelines. But even on Stack Overflow, only *code* or equivalent are formatted with backticks. For a more in-depth explanation, see the link I gave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to transfer a character between leagues "on demand". Generally speaking, you'll have to create a new character in the league your friends are in. Or they'll have to create one in yours.

However, leagues can have rules concerning character transferral/demotion to a different league. This usually happens on the character's death (for hardcore leagues) and the season ending (for challenge leagues).

Comment: I guess I'm going to create new characters. I hate that...

Comment: And also note that the stash is not share-able between characters in different leagues.  That stinks also.